# Saving different texts in database. Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

It is about web application written in Python and Django.
I want from users to give their consent about using the personal data they provide and save the consent in database.

The consent model:

```
class Consent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The user gives his consent on webpage on which is displayed the consent policy, a checkbox and a submit button.
I want to save the text which the user see when giving consent (the consent policy) in the Consent model, for every user. So later when I change the consent policy text, I can know which text the user saw when giving consent (for legal purposes).

I don't know if it is good to save the text in the database for every consent given. Currently the text is around 55 words and 350 characters long.

Is there a better way than just adding

```
consent_policy = models.TextField()
```

line to the consent model?

What is more, I am supporting two different languages so my texts are in separate django.po files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the entire text you can create another subject

```
class Consent(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    version = models.IntegerField()
```

Then you can just register as Foreginkey inside your user model to track which version the user read

```
class YourUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    consent = models.ForeignKey(Consent)
    name = models.CharField(length=30)
```